# How to define interceptors using annotations in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, xml-configuration, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm trying to use the `struts2-convention-plugin` which provides Java annotations to define Struts2 components.

With `Action`s so far so good but how can I use annotations to define interceptors ? (I'm talking of `@InterceptorRefs` or `@InterceptorRef`).

Is this even possible ? At the moment I've configured actions with annotations and interceptors in the `struts.xml` file.

Is it possible to completely eliminate the `struts.xml` file and use a 100% annotation oriented configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [struts2-convention-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/) doesn't replace XWork and its configuration which is xml based.

So, you cannot eliminate a need of `struts.xml` if you are using custom interceptors. For reference and explanation of the convention plugin usage see docs.